# Can anything bad happen, if I clear my array by assigning a non-initialized array to it in pascal?

Tags: delphi, pascal, freepascal

In pascal, the only way I dared cleaning my array was to simply iterate through it and clear it, but it is extremely inefficient. Can't I simply reinitialize it by assigning an empty array to it?

```
program arrays;
  var
    working, empty : array [1..10] of integer;
begin
  working[3] := 5;
  working:= empty;
end.
```

Is is ok to do this, can this backfire?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is absolutely fine. The semantics of the code are exactly what you need. Certainly the Delphi compiler will emit code to perform a simple and efficient memory copy. The compiler is able to do that because you have a fixed length array whose elements are simple value types. I'd be surprised if FPC did not produce very similar code.

Even if your array contained managed types (it doesn't), the assignment operator would result in code that respected those managed types.

As a final comment, the array full of zeros should be a constant.

Comment: OK then, I guess I will be clearing arrays this way, memory-wise, however, I believe it is not as efficient, as it uses double the amount of memory, right?

Comment: That's true. If you wanted to avoid keeping an extra array then you'd use `FillChar`. Which would be fine so long as your array holds value types.

Comment: Would you still use `FillChar` in this Unicode day and age? Or is the name a red-herring from days gone by?

Comment: @MarjanVenema Personally I would not. I personally would write it like this: `TArray.Initialise<Integer>(working, 0);` using my own `TArray` class which extends `Generics.Collections.TArray` with a bunch of useful static class methods.

Comment: LOL I knew you would have something like that behind the scenes!

Comment: @MarjanVenema Also, Unicode and `FillChar` don't interact. It's just that `FillChar` is incorrectly named. It should be `FillByte`.

Comment: Ah so, a red-herring regardless of days gone by :)

Comment: I believe the `advanced` method you wrote, would be too overkill for what I need, but thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

If you want to *clear* the array, writing:

```
working:= empty;
```

will in fact do the clearing, by *copying* the `empty` array content into `working`... in your case `empty` is void, since it is a *global variable*, so initialized with 0.

IMHO it is not a good practice to define such global variables. Global variables are evil in most cases (unless you know what you are doing), and in case of declaring them to be initialized with 0 does not make sense.

In fact, if `empty` is initialized on the stack (i.e. a `var` within a method), it is filled with whatever is on the stack at this time, i.e. some random data.

If you want to fast initialize an array which does not contain any reference counted types (like `string`), you can write:

```
fillchar(working,sizeof(working),0);
```

And if your array contains managed types, you can write:

```
finalize(workingWithStringInside); // to safely release internal managed types
fillchar(workingWithStringInside,sizeof(workingWithStringInside),0);
```

This is the faster code possible (faster than a variable copy), and sounds a better option.

Comment: Why is it faster? I'd expect for a small array the assignment would be hard to beat. For larger arrays you'l run out of processor cache. Of course, I don't expect that performance is critical here and premature optimisation is the root of all evil. Personally I'd never use the FillChar approach. I'd use a generic function that performed the fill in a loop with an assignment.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Assignment = Read + Write; FillChar = Write; Loop = count*Write. A loop can definitively be fast enough in practice, but slower than fillchar. For simple array of integer arrays, it is fine. But possibly hard to maintain for an array of record, since all members have to be explicitly named and assigned to null. This may be confusing. If you work with fixed-size arrays, fillchar is IMHO a good option. If you want something clean, fast & high-level, a dynamic array, or a dedicated generic type is the best way.

Comment: A null record const nullrec: TMyRec=() can be used, or Default(TMyRec) in modern delphi

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is not to set your length of the variable in the type...and use SetLength to initialize the array for you... from Delphi help: ***When S is a dynamic array of types that must be initialized, newly allocated space is set to 0 or nil.***

```
type
  TIntArray =  Array of Integer;

procedure WorkArrays(var aWorking: array of integer);
begin
  if High(aWorking) >= 0 then
    aWorking[0] := 1;
  if High(aWorking) >= 3 then
    aWorking[3] := 5;
end;

procedure WorkArrays2(var aWorking: array of integer);
begin
  if High(aWorking) >= 1 then
    aWorking[1] := 4;
  if High(aWorking) >= 9 then
    aWorking[9] := 7;
end;

procedure WorkArrays3(var aWorking: TIntArray);
begin
  SetLength(aWorking, 0);
  SetLength(aWorking, 4);
  aWorking[0] := 1;
  aWorking[3] := 5;
end;

procedure WorkArrays4(var aWorking: TIntArray);
begin
  SetLength(aWorking, 0);
  SetLength(aWorking, 10);
  aWorking[1] := 4;
  aWorking[9] := 7;
end;

procedure TForm58.ShowArrays(aWorking: array of integer);
var
  a_Index: integer;
begin
  for a_Index := Low(aWorking) to High(aWorking) do
    Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(aWorking[a_Index]));
end;

procedure TForm58.ShowArrays2(aWorking: TIntArray);
var
  a_Index: integer;
begin
  for a_Index := Low(aWorking) to High(aWorking) do
    Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(aWorking[a_Index]));
end;

procedure TForm58.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  a_MyArray: array of integer;
  a_MyArray1: TIntArray;
begin
  //SetLength(aWorking, 0);
  SetLength(a_MyArray, 3);//note this is a Zero based Array...0 to 2
  WorkArrays(a_MyArray);//note aWorking[3] will not show...because High is 2...
  ShowArrays(a_MyArray);
  SetLength(aWorking, 0);
  SetLength(a_MyArray, 10);//note this is a Zero based Array...0 to 9
  WorkArrays2(a_MyArray);
  ShowArrays(a_MyArray);
  WorkArrays3(a_MyArray1);
  ShowArrays2(a_MyArray1);
  WorkArrays4(a_MyArray1);
  ShowArrays2(a_MyArray1);
end;
```

Comment: I tried initializing array with SetLength even before I asked this question, I'm pretty sure id didn't work.

Comment: Did you set it to zero?  That will make sure you are working with a clean array.